# Custom Junit runner doesn't ignore tests with Assume.assumeTrue(someFalseCondition)

Tags: java, junit, junit-runner

I have written a custom Junit runner to have control on how to run Parameterized Tests. Below is the source code for it.

The problem is that now the class extending from it doesn't honor Assume.assumeTrue(someFalseCondition). Instead of the test being ignored it fails with exception like this

```
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: got: <false>, expected: is <true>
    at org.junit.Assume.assumeThat(Assume.java:70)
    at org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(Assume.java:39)
    at org.terracotta.tests.base.AbstractTestBase.setUp(AbstractTestBase.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
```

Is there anything i am missing in this class below.

```
public class TcTestRunner extends Suite {
  /**
   * Annotation for a method which provides parameters to be injected into the test class constructor by
   * <code>Parameterized</code>
   */
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  public static @interface Configs {
    // Empty Annotation
  }

  private class TestClassRunnerForParameters extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    private final int              fParameterSetNumber;

    private final List<TestConfig> fParameterList;

    TestClassRunnerForParameters(Class<?> type, List<TestConfig> parameterList, int i) throws InitializationError {
      super(type);
      fParameterList = parameterList;
      fParameterSetNumber = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object createTest() throws Exception {
      return getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor().newInstance(computeParams());
    }

    private TestConfig computeParams() throws Exception {
      try {
        return fParameterList.get(fParameterSetNumber);
      } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new Exception(String.format("%s.%s() must return a Collection of arrays.", getTestClass().getName(),
                                          getParametersMethod(getTestClass()).getName()));
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
      return String.format(fParameterList.get(fParameterSetNumber).getConfigName());
    }

    @Override
    protected String testName(final FrameworkMethod method) {
      return String.format("%s[%s]", method.getName(),     fParameterList.get(fParameterSetNumber).getConfigName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void validateConstructor(List<Throwable> errors) {
      validateOnlyOneConstructor(errors);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement classBlock(RunNotifier notifier) {
      return childrenInvoker(notifier);
    }
  }

  private final ArrayList<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<Runner>();

  /**
   * Only called reflectively. Do not use programmatically.
   */
  public TcTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws Throwable {
    super(klass, Collections.<Runner> emptyList());
    List<TestConfig> parametersList = getParametersList(getTestClass());
    for (int i = 0; i < parametersList.size(); i++)
      runners.add(new TestClassRunnerForParameters(getTestClass().getJavaClass(), parametersList, i));
  }

  @Override
  protected List<Runner> getChildren() {
    return runners;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private List<TestConfig> getParametersList(TestClass klass) throws Throwable {
    return (List<TestConfig>) getParametersMethod(klass).invokeExplosively(null);
  }

  private FrameworkMethod getParametersMethod(TestClass testClass) throws Exception {
    List<FrameworkMethod> methods = testClass.getAnnotatedMethods(Configs.class);
    for (FrameworkMethod each : methods) {
      int modifiers = each.getMethod().getModifiers();
      if (Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) && Modifier.isPublic(modifiers)) return each;
    }

    throw new Exception("No public static parameters method on class " + testClass.getName());
  }

}
```

Comment: Is this the complete stacktrace? There doesn't seem to be any mention of your test runner in there. Also, which version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: I think i got the problem, i had Assume.assumeTrue(someCondition) in a try catch block and hence my code was throwing the exception.